# IE8 Compatibility and Document mode

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, meta-tags

I want to make IE 8 understand my site as IE8. And not in IE7, compatibility mode, etc.

I have had a lot of issues to do this, even the same site in my localhost was different that in the production server. (Never mind what language, happened with: php and asp.net).

I've been watching these links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817574.aspx

But I cound not get anything.

**Update**:

Yes, that is exactly what I want, force IE not to render the page in compatibility mode

Comment: You have not asked an actual question. :) Please rephrase.

Comment: He probably wants a way to force IE *not to render the page in compatibility mode*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get much of [your link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx) either, but when I changed the language to English, it became [rather comprehensible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx).

Have you tried

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

That should tell IE8 to render the page using the latest IE engine and settings, with no "old browser emulation".

Comment: I added the meta tag you tell me Andreas. It worked to change the Document mode to IE8 standars, but the browser mode is still in IE8 Compatibility.

Comment: The point of the meta tag is that you can decide when your design if ready for newer browser versions and emulate older versions. You shouldn't use `IE=edge` for prodution uses, but `IE=EmulateIE8` (or possibly `IE=EmulateIE9`).

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand the difference between Browser Mode and Document Mode.

Document Mode is under the control of the document. Setting the X-UA-Compatible or DocType controls the Document Mode.

Browser Mode is NOT under the control of the document, and affects the User-Agent String and Conditional Comments/Version Vector. Browser Mode is controlled by the user's Compatibility View settings, and the URL of the document. If the document is on your Intranet, for instance, by default it is in the Compatibility Browser Mode. This can be disabled by clicking Tools > Compatibility View Settings > and unticking "Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View."

You can see  (and temporarily override) both modes in the IE Developer Tools (hit F12).