# How to force to open a Page in Document Mode as IE8

Tags: jsf-2, internet-explorer-8, doctype, intranet

We have deployed our webapp, which was developed with JSF, Spring and Hibernate on Tomcat server in our internal network (intranet). When I test in my application in local it's working fine.

But once I deploy to **DEV** I come across style issues. When I have two dropdowns one after another, the top dropdown overlaps with another one.

This happens when I have Document Mode set to "IE7 standards." When I change Document Mode to "IE8 standards," everything works fine.

To force Document Mode to IE8 standards, I tried this meta tag in my  section of the HTML document [according to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652870/ie8-compability-and-document-mode), but it didn't work for me:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

How can I force my page to render according to IE8 standards on the intranet? Does my application render in IE8 standards on the internet?

EDIT :I see something in my develoer tools.Even though I kept my `<meta>` it after `<head>` but my **primefaces styles and scripts** are loading before to that.How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad to tell I am finally able to resolve this issue by using this link in primefaces.And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860779/how-to-make-a-meta-tag-the-first-one-in-the-head-section) also helped to do it through entire application

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1433

Answer (score 1):

Odd, [this item](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/afb57ce6-d149-4a09-8811-63c0645c92e6) was posted yesterday, not sure if it applies to your situation:

> IE 8 will ignore the x-ua-compatible setting if it comes after the stylesheets.  In order for IE to acknowledge the meta setting, put it at the top.

Comment: @mcknz...Thanks for quick reply.I didn't see this link until you posted here. But I already tried by keeping that meta at the top.But still no luck.And FYI it's only happening in DEV.And When we specify as intranet doesn't my localhost come under intranet?It's working fine in local.

Comment: @mcknz....Just to be clear when you specify "put it at the top" means does it need to just right after <head> in html page or anywhere but after <style> tag?

Comment: I took it to mean anywhere but before style tag, but that wouldn't explain why it only happens it DEV though...

Comment: @mcknz.........Cause DEV is on intranet.So, IE automatically detect Intranet and force my application to run on 'IE7 Doucment mode' which is the important in rendering any page.But not sure even localhost also in intranet work, not happening in that?